# 800A03EC error while opening excel via vb script

Tags: excel, vbscript

I started vb scripting very recently and compiled a vb script (of course googling) to open the excel sheet. However I am getting  800A03EC error - Sorry we could not find the excel sheet. Is it renamed/moved or deleted?

[image]

I can manually open the file manually without any error.

Is this because of document classification?

Here is my code

```
Option Explicit

Sub FileSplit()

Dim Workbook
Dim Worksheet
Dim fileName
Dim filePath
Dim objExcel
Dim objWorkbook
Dim rowCount
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
MsgBox ("Hello World")
filePath = locateFile() 


If filePath = "" Then 
   MsgBox "Operation canceled", vbcritical 
Else 
   wscript.echo filePath
   fileName = Mid(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "\") + 1)
   wscript.echo fileName
End If 

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  

objExcel.Visible = True  

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(fileName) 
Set objWorkbook = Activeworkbook 

End Sub


Function locateFile() 
    locateFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( _ 
    "mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=f>" & _ 
    "<script>resizeTo(0,0);f.click();new ActiveXObject  ('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" & _ 
 ".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(f.value);close();</script>""" _ 
      ).StdOut.ReadLine() 


End Function


call FileSplit
```

many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are purposely extracting file name out of the full path to pass to Excel. Pass the full path instead.

Comment: IIRC Excel defaults to looking in your My Documents folder if you don't supply a path

Comment: Thanks a ton .@GSerg, @oracle certified professional, its working fine now.